# Finding this particular data in website using selenium or python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

If the website has 'data-optanongroupid' then true if not then ignore stating that website is not containing data-optanongroupid.

website :'https://www.zmrzlina-misa.cz/

this data not present in website source page, how to handle in this case
when this is not class, id or any element
just wants to consider and check this data is present or not using selenium or python, is it possible to any other ways to deal.

[image: just wants to consider and check this data is present or not using selenium or python]

```
driver.get('https://www.zmrzlina-misa.cz/')
time.sleep(3)
soup_selenium = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser") 
print(soup_selenium)
```

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: print(soup_selenium) here can see that particular data-optanongroupid present

Comment: So what do you want to do? Do you want to open page and wait some time until node with `data-optanongroupid` attribute appear in DOM?

Comment: how to check data-optanongroupid availed or not i have 1000 of websites need to put this condition to say cookie present

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to wait few seconds for required element to appear:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.zmrzlina-misa.cz")

time_to_wait = 5

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, time_to_wait).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-optanongroupid]"))
    )
    print('Element with "data-optanongroupid" attribute found')
except:
    print('No elements with "data-optanongroupid" attribute found')
```

If it found add your code to `try` block, if not found - to `except` block